# Have the program read an ini file to select and activate different windows

Tags: c#, ini, setforegroundwindow

I want to write a small app that switches between different windows at 6 second intervals.
It will all be explorer url's but they will change from time to time (daily), therefore I want to create a ini file where I can update the url daily, and then have the app switch between active windows based on the ini file description.
The url will be something like

`http://servername.test.lab:8081/OVPM?ACTION=LOADSTATE&STATENAME=domain_Servers_Disk_Utilization&CUSTOMER=`

I have OMW urls for disk utilization, memory cpu etc and want to switch between them.
So my question is

1. how can I use SetForegroundWindow() based on url (will the windows title work for a webpage)?
2. how can I have C# use the ini to the read the url to use `SetForegroundWindow()`
3. should I use a different method

Comment: Are you sure you should use different windows? Such things are typically done by showing one window with alternating content (which also allows you to animate that, e.g. blending).

Comment: People still use ini files?!

Comment: @Mario - Id prefer different windows so that each window can be full screen, and the urls differ quite a bit (different sources and servers etc)

Comment: @DavidG Any file that can be easily changed and still have the app read it will do :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:
WPF or windows forms app with webbrowser control and a timer.
Drop the ini
Create a little database with a table. 
URL
Interval
Set your timer interval from the interval propperty on the db.
on tick() event; grab next url, set the webbrowser control, and reload.

Later you can build a nice front end to edit the cycles configured in the db.

Comment: You assume he has a database to store data in. Personally for a single configuration setting I would use `app.config`.

Comment: @DavidG True. App.Config will be perfect for this.